# How can I make my TCP listening app safer?

Tags: c++, tcp, listen, honeypot

I’m looking for advice on writing a very safe C/C++ app that will listen to a tcp port. I'd like to peek at what others are trying to do to my machine, but I’d rather not install an elaborate honeypot app if I can do what I need with a very short program. With my goal being simple and safe, I want to make sure I handle at least the following:
1) The client should not be able to send an unlimited amount of data,
2) The client(s) should not be able to overload the server with too many connections and
3) The client should not be able to keep a connection open indefinitely.
Because my current app is small and functional, a third party library doesn't seem warranted for this project. However, a small library that would simplify the app further would be interesting. Also, I expect the C++ standard library may help in simplifying my code.

Below are some key functions from my initial attempt. This code compiles on Windows, OSX and Linux.

How can I make the app safer, or simpler?

```
void SafeClose(SOCKET s)
{
    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
        return;
    shutdown(s, SHUT_RDWR);
    closesocket(s);
}

void ProcessConnection(SOCKET sock, sockaddr_in *sockAddr)
{
    time_t time1;
    char szTime[TIME_BUF_SIZE];
    char readBuf[READ_BUF_SIZE];

    time(&time1);
    strftime(szTime, TIME_BUF_SIZE-1, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S", localtime(&time1)); 
    printf("%s - %s\n", szTime, inet_ntoa(sockAddr->sin_addr));
    usleep(1000000);       // Wait 1 second for client to send something
    int actualReadCount = recv(sock, readBuf, READ_BUF_SIZE-1, 0); 

    if (actualReadCount < 0 || actualReadCount >= READ_BUF_SIZE){
        actualReadCount = 0;
        strcpy(readBuf, "(Nothing)");
    } else {
        CleanString(readBuf, actualReadCount); // Replace non-printable characters
        readBuf[actualReadCount] = 0;
    }

    printf("%s\n\n", readBuf);
    SafeClose(sock);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int             port            = 80;
    char            cmd[CMD_BUF_SIZE]   = {0};
    sockaddr_in     newSockAddr;
    sockaddr_in     localSockAddr;

    if(argc < 2){
        printf("Usage: safelisten PORT\n\n");
        return error_code;
    }

    error_code++;
    port = atoi(argv[1]); 
    BuildCleanAsciiMap(); // Used to replace non-printable characters

    localSockAddr.sin_family        = AF_INET;              
    localSockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr   = INADDR_ANY;           
    localSockAddr.sin_port          = htons(port);          
    sizeNewSockAddr                 = sizeof newSockAddr;

    CHK( listenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0));
    CHK( setsockopt(listenSocket, SOL_SOCKET,  SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&on, sizeof(on)));
    CHK( bind(listenSocket, (sockaddr*)&localSockAddr, sizeof localSockAddr));
    CHK( listen(listenSocket, BACKLOG));
    CHK( SetNonBlocking(listenSocket));
    CHK( SetNonBlocking(0));        // Set STDIN to nonblocking for linux    
    printf ("Listening on port: %d\nEnter q to quit.\n\n", port);

    while(strcmp(cmd, "q")) // While the user has not entered q ...
    {
        newSocket = accept(listenSocket, (sockaddr*)&newSockAddr, &sizeNewSockAddr);
        ReadCmd(cmd, CMD_BUF_SIZE);

        if(newSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) { 
            // accept() would have blocked, thus we wait and try again
            usleep(10000);
            continue;   
        }

        // Set to nonblocking because we don't want the client to dictate how 
        // long we are connected.
        CHK( SetNonBlocking(newSocket)); 
        ProcessConnection(newSocket, &newSockAddr);
    }

    SafeClose(listenSocket);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the only real "slow" thing I can see is your network connection. I don't see how this can be done any faster.  What makes you think it's slow?

Comment: If you want to use the C++ Standard lib, then the C tag is not appropriate.

Comment: [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/)?

Comment: Don't call "usleep" inside ProcessConnection.  Call "select" to wait for data on the socket.  Otherwise, you just waste an entire second if data is available immediately.

Comment: `I'd rather not rely on third party libraries` - then 9 times out of 10 you're going to do it wrong. It is impossible to know everything and security is not easy to achieve (that's really 9 people out of 10, and it is rather mildly put, IMO)

Comment: Why write something yourself -- look at `netcat` (`nc`) or `socat` and see if those can be used for your purposes first.

Comment: Tony - Speed is not the primary issue in my case. My main concern is safety and simplicity.

Comment: selbie - I can't use select on Windows with stdin and sockets. I need to monitor the keyboard and the listen socket while keeping the code simple.

Comment: Though I'd rather not use a third party library I'd consider it. If the library is small, open source, doesn't have a lot of features I don't need, and simplifies my code that would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2) The client(s) should not be able to overload the server with too
>   many connections...

Your best options is letting the router limit how many connections an IP address makes, as, by the time your program gets the connection info there are system resources already allocated.

> 1) The client should not be able to send an unlimited amount of data,

The best option is to have some reasonable max that can be sent, and just keep track of how much you have read, and once you reach the max limit, close the connection.

> 3) The client should not be able to keep a connection open indefinitely.

For this, you can just create a thread that will start a countdown, so when a connection has been open for a specific amount of time, it can timeout and you can just close the connection.

There are other, more complicated, solutions, but I think this would be a good starting point.

If you want to do something about (2), keep a hashmap in memory and just increment how many connections have been made, but you may also want to keep track of time.  You want the data structure to be very fast, so you can decide if you need to disconnect the connection early.

For example, if you had two longs in the hashmap, then you could put the time (in unixtime or ticks) of the first connection, and increment, and if you get 10 connections in less than one minute, start to close the excess until a minute has passed. Then remove that element if it has had connections long enough that you trust it was not attacking you.

Also, make certain you validate all the parameters being passed to you, and have reasonable max values for any strings.

Comment: Thank you James, your point for item 2 is helpful. But I am curious about resources allocated since I set BACKLOG to 5 for the listen call. Would that limit the resources the clients could take? For items 1 and 3, do you think I've handled these adequately in my code shown?

Comment: @Mark - The problem is that your webserver has already allocated a thread for that connection, so some memory was allocated, and network traffic was send/received just for the http request.

Comment: @Mark - There are some issues but the main one is what if it takes more than 1 second for someone to send all the data. Then anything sent after 1 second is lost. It depends on your ultimate goal with this code.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to safely peek at what clients may be trying to send to my machine. There is no great loss if I miss some of the data. If some protocols require my server to transmit first then nothing will be sent or received, not a problem. But if the client protocol does initiate the transmit, I was guessing that one second would allow enough to be sent so that I could identify the protocol for the majority of the cases. If client/net/protocol is slower in a few cases I will miss those. When testing with several browsers, I got the info I needed in 1 sec, but I can change if needed.